# How do I run a .java file from the command line, Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to run my main class which is present in the src/comm instead of src/java/main.

I tried using:

```
mvn exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=src.communication.Launcher.Launcher
```

This statement gives me the "class not found exception".

The hierarchy is like src/communication is the source folder, then Launcher is package and the Launcher.java is the class file.

How can I execute this file from the command line as my main function is inside this class?

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: Please move you source classes to `src/java/main`.

Comment: That is the last option , but is there any other way do execute my class file with the same heirarchy??

Comment: If you use maven, you should use it correctly. Why do you want to move them?

Comment: If you want to use maven in this way it could be better to use a simple Eclipse project. If you want to use maven you should structure your project as maven standard directory layout. And then things will get easier.

Comment: Nothing wrong with putting source files somewhere else than `src/main/java`, but one should have a solid knowledge on java packages and how maven works before doings so (and a good reason)

Comment: All these tools have certain *base paradigms* that guide their usage. When you decide to come up with your own stuff, you basically start fighting your toolset. All the time. Simple answer: don't try to adapt the tool to your (most likely not well thought) "ideas". Instead: really learn *how* the tools do their work, and follow that. Inventing your own stuff  you only do when there are very good reasons to.

Comment: Maven -> configuration by convention

Comment: I am using maven only for the benefits its provide with the pom.xml as I will be handling lot of dependencies to handle .

Comment: you canalso configure the path of sources in `pom.xml` file: `<build>
        <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>`

Answer (score 1):

Use **maven-jar-plugin** and put in the **manifest** in your main class,
but it is better to use src/java/main than the other folder.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                       <mainClass>pacakgeAndClasseName</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```